# Parentheses matching in Scala --- functional approach

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Let's say I want to parse a string with various opening and closing brackets (I used parentheses in the title because I believe it is more common -- the question is the same nevertheless) so that I get all the higher levels separated in a list.

Given:

```
[hello:=[notting],[hill]][3.4(4.56676|5.67787)][the[hill[is[high]]not]]
```

I want:

```
List("[hello:=[notting],[hill]]", "[3.4(4.56676|5.67787)]", "[the[hill[is[high]]not]]")
```

The way I am doing this is by counting the opening and closing brackets and adding to the list whenever I get my counter to 0. However, I have an ugly imperative code. You may assume that the original string is well formed.

My question is: what would be a nice functional approach to this problem?

Notes: I have thought of using the for...yield construct but given the use of the counters I cannot get a simple conditional (I must have conditionals just for updating the counters as well) and I do not know how I could use this construct in this case.

Comment: See "parser combinators": http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scala+parser+combinators

Comment: A similar case: http://blog.tmorris.net/haskell-scala-java-7-functional-java-java/. The code in the comments is the most useful bit.

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov, everytime I play with parser combinators I feel like I will need more experience with it to be proficient to get a solution in an almost certain time. Is it overkill here?

Comment: Certainly, parser combinators is quite generic tool. When you know how to use it, you'll be able to come up with a reliable solution pretty quickly and with more readable code. As usual, this is a tradeoff ("maintenance costs" vs. "performance"), as a hand-written algorithm will most likely be more performant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick solution using Scala parser combinator library:

```
import util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

object Parser extends RegexParsers {
  lazy val t = "[^\\[\\]\\(\\)]+".r

  def paren: Parser[String] =
    ("(" ~ rep1(t | paren) ~ ")" |
     "[" ~ rep1(t | paren) ~ "]") ^^ {
      case o ~ l ~ c => (o :: l ::: c :: Nil) mkString ""
    }

  def all = rep(paren)

  def apply(s: String) = parseAll(all, s)
}
```

Checking it in REPL:

```
scala> Parser("[hello:=[notting],[hill]][3.4(4.56676|5.67787)][the[hill[is[high]]not]]")
res0: Parser.ParseResult[List[String]] = [1.72] parsed: List([hello:=[notting],[hill]], [3.4(4.56676|5.67787)], [the[hill[is[high]]not]])
```

Comment: It seems so easy when you do it. I've spent like a couple hours overall on this and what I had was more or less like that: `"[" ~ rep(paren ~ opt(t)) ~ "]" | "[" ~ rep(t ~ opt(paren)) ~ "]"`.

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
def split(input: String): List[String] = {
  def loop(pos: Int, ends: List[Int], xs: List[String]): List[String] =
    if (pos >= 0)
      if ((input charAt pos) == ']') loop(pos-1, pos+1 :: ends, xs)
      else if ((input charAt pos) == '[')
        if (ends.size == 1) loop(pos-1, Nil, input.substring(pos, ends.head) :: xs)
        else loop(pos-1, ends.tail, xs)
      else loop(pos-1, ends, xs)
    else xs
  loop(input.length-1, Nil, Nil)
}

scala> val s1 = "[hello:=[notting],[hill]][3.4(4.56676|5.67787)][the[hill[is[high]]not]]"
s1: String = [hello:=[notting],[hill]][3.4(4.56676|5.67787)][the[hill[is[high]]not]]

scala> val s2 = "[f[sad][add]dir][er][p]"
s2: String = [f[sad][add]dir][er][p]

scala> split(s1) foreach println
[hello:=[notting],[hill]]
[3.4(4.56676|5.67787)]
[the[hill[is[high]]not]]

scala> split(s2) foreach println
[f[sad][add]dir]
[er]
[p]
```

Comment: +1, my answer was based on the specific case, and not the generic one, which clearly requires a more complex, and apparently iterative, solution.

Answer (score 2):

Given your requirements counting the parenthesis seems perfectly fine. How would you do that in a functional way? You can make the state explicitly passed around.

So first we define our state which accumulates results in `blocks` or concatenates the next `block` and keeps track of the depth:

```
case class Parsed(blocks: Vector[String], block: String, depth: Int)
```

Then we write a pure function that processed that returns the next state. Hopefully, we can just carefully look at this one function and ensure it's correct.

```
def nextChar(parsed: Parsed, c: Char): Parsed = {
  import parsed._
  c match {
    case '[' | '(' => parsed.copy(block = block + c,
                                  depth = depth + 1)
    case ']' | ')' if depth == 1 
                   => parsed.copy(blocks = blocks :+ (block + c),
                                  block = "",
                                  depth = depth - 1)
    case ']' | ')' => parsed.copy(block = block + c,
                                  depth = depth - 1)
    case _         => parsed.copy(block = block + c)
  }
}
```

Then we just used a `foldLeft` to process the data with an initial state:

```
val data = "[hello:=[notting],[hill]][3.4(4.56676|5.67787)][the[hill[is[high]]not]]"
val parsed = data.foldLeft(Parsed(Vector(), "", 0))(nextChar) 
parsed.blocks foreach println
```

Which returns:

```
[hello:=[notting],[hill]]
[3.4(4.56676|5.67787)]
[the[hill[is[high]]not]]
```

Comment: Dammit, I’ve just had the very same idea.

Answer (score 2):

You have an ugly imperative solution, so why not make a good-looking one? :)

This is an imperative translation of huynhjl's solution, but just posting to show that sometimes imperative is concise and perhaps easier to follow.

```
  def parse(s: String) = {
    var res = Vector[String]()
    var depth = 0
    var block = ""
    for (c <- s) {
      block += c
      c match {
        case '[' => depth += 1
        case ']' => depth -= 1
                    if (depth == 0) {
                      res :+= block
                      block = ""
                    }
        case _   =>
      }
    }
    res
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val s = "[hello:=[notting],[hill]][3.4(4.56676|5.67787)][the[hill[is[high]]not]]"
s.split("]\\[").toList
```

returns:

```
List[String](
  [hello:=[notting],[hill],
  3.4(4.56676|5.67787),
  the[hill[is[high]]not]]
)
```

Comment: See this example: "[f[sad][add]dir][er][p]".
What you suggested clearly does not solve the general case. Besides, I am not looking for a quick fix, I have a perfectly working code.

Comment: was operating on the specific case supplied. @hyunhjl's answer in particular is quite interesting...